# Display multiple markers on Google Map from data in html table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I'm trying to display a marker on a google map for each row of a html table loaded on the same page.

So the html table has the headers "Site", "Lat" and "Lon". I need to use JQuery to scrape the row values and put them into var locations for the google map which will be displayed below the table for this example (I need it above the table for my application but I can do that myself once it works).

I've nearly got it but just can't get it to work.

---

**HTML**

```
<table>
<thead>
  <th> Site </th>
  <th> Lat </th>
  <th> Lon </th>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Site 1</td>
            <td>53.19373465</td>
            <td>-6.39347735</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Site 2</td>
            <td>53.19373465</td>
            <td>-6.39347735</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Site 3</td>
            <td>53.19373465</td>
            <td>-6.39347735</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script
  src=
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1tbIAqN0XqcgTR1-          FxYoVTVq6Is6lD98">
</script>

 <body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="default" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
 </body>
```

---

**CSS**

```
html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
  table { border: 1px solid black;}
  th { border: 1px solid black;}
  td { border: 1px solid black;}
```

---

**Javascript/JQuery**

```
var table = $("table tbody");

    table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
            siteName = $tds.eq(0).text(),
            Lat = $tds.eq(1).text();
            Lon = $tds.eq(2).text();
        // do something with siteName, timeStamp, Lat, Lon
        var locations = [('[' + siteName
              + ',' + Lat
              + ',' + Lon + ']')];
    });

  function initialize() {

    var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3242381,-6.3857877),
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("default"),
        myOptions);

    setMarkers(map,locations)

  }



  function setMarkers(map,locations){

      var marker, i

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
 {  

 var loan = locations[i][0]
 var lat = locations[i][1]
 var long = locations[i][2]

  latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
          map: map, title: loan , position: latlngset  
        });
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())


        var content = "Site: " + loan +  '</h3>'    

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
        return function() {
           infowindow.setContent(content);
           infowindow.open(map,marker);
        };
    })(marker,content,infowindow)); 

  }
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2crQ7/894/

Comment: Are you not aware of the fact that your content should be inside `<body>` tag? If not I suggest learning basic HTML before doing DOM manipulation... There are many mistakes like the scope of variables (`var locations`) which are very basic...

Comment: Is it definitely MooTools you're using?

Comment: @ T J yes I am aware, the html code here is just for example/JSfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bangsi/wv1jawhL/1/)

You're almost there, I've cleaned up the process a little but this will get it working - you're table has 3 markers in the same location too so you may want to change that.

```
var table = $("table tbody");

function attainLocation() {
    var tableLocs = [];
    table.find('tr').each(function(i) {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
            siteName = $tds.eq(0).text(),
            Lat = $tds.eq(1).text();
        Lon = $tds.eq(2).text();
        var obj = {
            'sitename': siteName,
            'lat': Lat,
            'lon': Lon
        };
        tableLocs.push(obj);
    });
    return tableLocs;
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function initialize() {

    var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.3242381, -6.3857877),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("default"),
        myOptions);

    var locations = attainLocation();
    setMarkers(map, locations)

}

function setMarkers(map, locations) {

    var marker, i

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        var loan = locations[i].sitename
        var lat = locations[i].lat
        var long = locations[i].lon

        latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            title: loan,
            position: latlngset
        });
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())


        var content = "Site: " + loan + '</h3>'

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content, infowindow) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            };
        })(marker, content, infowindow));

    }
}
```